# Authorize.net 'Test Webhook' port 3000 Error occurred in connecting to the endpoint

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-webhooks

- My webhook endpoint is HTTPS secured and the app is running at port 3000
- The backend code is Node js.
- endpoint e.g: ssl_secured_website:3000/notify (POST)
- When I Hit on Test Webhook I get this error: Error:
  An error occurred in connecting to the endpoint: ssl_secured_website:3000/notify
- I tried port 80, 443 nothing is working
- I am actually able to get 200 Response via POSTMAN
- As soon as request is received, I am immediately returning 200 status

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO2SP.png)

[image]

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I'm using ngrok to serve my local site.

Comment: Did you happen to solve this issue. I'm experiencing the same problem.